# В мобильной версии сайта подчёркивание текста сливается с нижними закорючками букв

Tags: вёрстка, frontend, шрифты

Можно ли исправить проблему без замены шрифта или задания `border` для каждого `underline` элемента?
Менять `line-height` и `font-size` уже пробовал.

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1):

```html
<p><span style="border-bottom:1px solid;padding:0px;">Привет</span> как дела что делаешь</p>
```

Comment: так подчёркивание мне нужно

Comment: исправил сообщение выше

Answer (score 0):

С `text-decoration: underline;` такого не получится сделать. Нужно поставить `text-decoration: none;` и `border-bottom: 1px #цвет_ссылки solid;`. Или поменяйте шрифт на другой.